# How to find the sum of a temporary column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this code:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 100 AS TempColumn
FROM MyTable;
```

And the table is this:

```
| ID | Name | TempColumn|
-------------------------
| 1  |  A   |   100     |
-------------------------
| 2  |  B   |   100     |
-------------------------
| 3  |  C   |   100     |
-------------------------
| 1  |  A   |   100     |
-------------------------
| 4  |  D   |   100     |
-------------------------
```

Now I want to find the sum of the |TempColumn| where ID=1.
So it should look like this:

```
| ID | Name | TempColumn|
-------------------------
| 1  |  A   |   200     |
-------------------------
```

How can I query this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to do this using a simple `GROUP BY` operation.

Comment: I've tried to compute the sum() using sub-queries but it doesn't work.

Comment: `SELECT id, Name, COUNT(id) * 100 FROM myTable WHERE id = 1 GROUP BY id, Name` should work for you.

Comment: SELECT ID, SUM(TempColumn) AS TempColumn
FROM Table WHERE ID = 1 GROUP BY ID

Comment: Also why does your question have both mysql and sql server tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum a constant:

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(100) AS SumOfTempColumn
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY ID, Name;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e135c/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Should this not be reasonably straight forward using an aggregate query?

```
SELECT  ID,
        Name,
        SUM(100) AS TempColumn
  FROM  MyTable
  GROUP BY ID, Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Name,SUM(TempColumn) AS TempColumn
FROM Table
WHERE ID = 1
GROUP BY ID, Name
```